# Custom search in an API

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

I have an API with a custom search over half a dozen fields, something along the lines of the following, although may also include sensitive data as I use the same approach for the same type of search elsewhere

- Username
- Email
- Firstname
- Lastname
- Department

I'm generally using a RESTful approach, so retrieving users would be something like the following for a list of users, or a single user

```
GET /user
GET /user/1
```

For the search, however, I'm slightly baffled as to how to allow this. My original intention was to use **JSON in the request body**, eg

```
{
    "username": "someuser",
    "department": "sales"
}
```

I can't use the request body as would seem logical (and as I use for POST etc actions), though, because it isn't supported by Chrome as far as I can tell (or at least, not by the PostMan addon, which we use for testing)

As such, what's the best way to perform this search?

The options I see

**Use a header**

Which seems like the "wrong" use of headers, but also the closest to the origial request body

**Use parameters in the URL**

eg

```
GET /user?username=someuser&department=sales
```

But that gets messy with the controller (using C# Web API), because I can't leave items blank. So the request would be more like this, unless I had a ton of overridden methods to handle the different permutations. This seems... messy

```
GET /user?username=someuser&email=&firstname=&lastname=&department=
```

Perhaps more importantly, it leaves a little too much visible "over the shoulder": this is within a healthcare setting, and while there are unavoidable times where things are displayed, I would rather keep this to a minimum (the data itself is, naturally, SSL encrypted during transmission)

**Use a different HTTP verb**

I could use POST or some other verb, which would work but is counter-intuitive and goes against both the RESTful approach (as far as I can tell) and my own standards within the project, so could be confusing.

Has anyone else run into this? What's the "official" or best way to handle it?

Comment: re: leaving items blank, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862069/optional-parameters-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Thanks, although I've just added a further objection to the URL parameter option - this is in a healthcare setting, so items in the URL, particularly once they're not obviously visible in the form the user is filling in, isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real "official" way. In this case, I would just bend the rules of REST a bit and just use a post, passing in a body is what POST-methods are for.

Regarding no support from Chrome: This is fully supported in Chrome as well as in the PostMan extension (you need to select a POST-method and choose the raw option for the body and then select JSON)

On the other hand, the querystring could also be a good option. You can have empty items by using default parameters in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string userName = "", int departmentId = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I may have to resort to bending the rules: you probably missed it as (from the timing of your post) I think I ninja-edited while you were writing your answer, but I have a further objection to putting search terms in the URL due to the setting the API is used

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed that. If indeed the data is sensitive, then it's better not to use GET at all. Which makes the choice for POST even more obvious

Comment: With SSL and no parameters, I'm not aware of a significant difference between POST and GET, but yeah it's looking like the only real option. I'm assuming you instantly discounted the header entirely?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't do that