# Web API to get input parameters to query Oracle Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-web-api

I am creating the Web API with four input parameters. The input parameters are going to be used in the where clause of the Select statement.The fields in Oracle are `ROOM (Varchar),SUBMIT_DATE(Date)(eg:01-JAN-16)`. The URL should be something like `/api/TGSSampleDatas?Room=654&SUBMITDATE='01-Jan-16'. So in C# I am creating the Controller with the Get action like

```
public class TGSSampleDatasController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM,DateTime ? SUBMITDATE = null)
        {
            List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
            List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = " + ROOM +"and SUBMIT_DATE =" +"'"+SUBMITDATE+"'";
           var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=TGSData.json", out contentDisposition))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }
            return response;
```

Getting the below error in the fiddler
`{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SUBMITDATE' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(System.String, System.DateTime)' in 'TGSSampleData.Controllers.TGSSampleDatasController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}`
[image]

Comment: Duplicate question, you can find the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862069/optional-parameters-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @Div when I try /api/TGSSampleDatas?Room=654&SUBMITDATE=01-Jan-16  error saying `An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: That is not the actual error, look at your stack trace.

Comment: Happening in Run time when debugging. I have added the screenshot

Comment: Also you are vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks when you use string concatenation, you should be using parameters.

Comment: @Igor Should I put ; at the end?

Comment: @trx - no, your sql statement was not well formed. You should be using parameters. See my answer below, this should fix it. Change your sql string to what I have and add those 2 parameters.

Comment: Seems like OP pointed out two different questions at once now, first pointed out the issue of  `parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SUBMITDATE'` and now the question is totally converted into [SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940471/sql-error-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended), where it seems like a duplicate question.

Comment: @trx - Did this solve your issue or do you have multiple issues like Div pointed out above?

Comment: @Igor yest using the parameters solved the issue. I have changed the Date in the input parameter not to be nullable. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sql statement is wrong.

```
"SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = " + ROOM +"and SUBMIT_DATE =" +"'"+SUBMITDATE+"'";
//--------------------------------no ticks-^----^ -no space--^
```

- Room is a string so if you were to use string concatination (**BUT DON'T**) you should enclose it with `'`, otherwise it becomes a part of the statement.
- Also there is no space between ROOM and `and`.

---

The real fix is to use parameters for both `ROOM` and `SUBMITDATE`. Doing this will prevent issues like that from happening to begin with.

*I am guessing on the parameter types, you might have to correct them.*

```
List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
prms.Add(new OracleParameter("ROOM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ROOM, ParameterDirection.Input));
prms.Add(new OracleParameter("SUBMITDATE", OracleDbType.Date, SUBMITDATE ?? System.DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Input));
// note that because you are using a nullable type as input you should pass in DBNull.Value as the value if the value is null in your c# code.

var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = :ROOM and SUBMIT_DATE = :SUBMITDATE";
```

String concatenation like you are doing makes your system vulnerable to sql injection attacks and adds issues to your sql code. The latter can be illustrated by passing in a value that contains a `'` mark. Do it again and you could end the sql statement and add another one at the end.