# How to pass option query string parameter which is of string type in Webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass a string parameter as querystring parameter which should be optional.

```
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] string Name, string Place)
```

Here I want Place as an optional parameter. I tried to use as
`string?Place=null`.
But It wont works for me.
Let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Change your method signature: `public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] string Name, string Place = null)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional query string parameters in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862069/optional-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] string Name, string Place = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to sen Place just don't put it in your url

```
...controller/test?Name=name
```

if you need both parameters

```
...controller/test?Name=name&Place=place
```

and you have to use FromUri for both parameters

```
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] string Name, [FromUri]string Place)
```

or maybe you can try dont'use at all

```
public IHttpActionResult Test( string Name, string Place)
```